# Which --broadcast-address should i set in nsqd param?

Tags: node.js, macos, broadcast, nsq

Now i am starting nsqd with
`nsqd --max-msg-timeout=1800000 --lookupd-tcp-address=127.0.0.1:4160`

I am using nsqjd for nodejs with nsq.
There was everyhing ok until some days.
Now, when starting nodejs with nsqjs in it i receive error:
`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND s-MacBook-Air.local s-MacBook-Air.local:4150
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:57:26)
Emitted 'error' event at:`

It seems, that i need to specify --broadcast-address (https://github.com/dudleycarr/nsqjs/issues/248#issuecomment-427571072).

But which address should i provide? I have tried the `'nsqd --max-msg-timeout=1800000 --lookupd-tcp-address=127.0.0.1:4160 --broadcast-address=localhost'` .

My local network address and `--broadcast-address=localhost':4160`  -nothing works. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried enclosing the values with ' ', like `lookupd-tcp-address='127.0.0.1:4160'`